# Windows 7 x64 blue screen of death

Tags: windows-7, bsod, hp-elitebook

I've been running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit on my HP EliteBook 8530w for a few months now, and during that time, it has blue-screen-of-deathed three times.

This time, I was able to snap a pic with my cellphone before it automatically rebooted:

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT:**

I ran BlueScreenView, which showed 6 crahes:

```
Bug Check String            Caused By Driver
----------------            ----------------
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL      hal.dll
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE  ntsokrnl.exe
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE  ntsokrnl.exe
BAD_POOL_CALLER             NETw5s64.sys
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION    ntsokrnl.exe
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE  ntsokrnl.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

In case this is a driver problem, you can use [BlueScreenView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to try and analyze the dumps:

> BlueScreenView scans all your minidump
>   files created during 'blue screen of
>   death' crashes, and displays the
>   information about all crashes in one
>   table. For each crash, BlueScreenView
>   displays the minidump filename, the
>   date/time of the crash, the basic
>   crash information displayed in the
>   blue screen (Bug Check Code and 4
>   parameters), **and the details of the driver or module that possibly caused the crash** (filename, product name,
>   file description, and file
>   version). 
> **For each crash displayed in the upper pane, you can view the details of the device drivers
>   loaded during the crash in the lower
>   pane**. **BlueScreenView also mark the
>   drivers that their addresses found in
>   the crash stack, so you can easily
>   locate the suspected drivers that
>   possibly caused the crash**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran BlueScreenView, which showed 6 crashes. I added a summary of its results to my original question.

Comment: What drivers, if any, are implicated ?

Answer (score 2):

Overheating (quite common in laptops) can sometimes cause this.
If the BIOS reports it, use that to find out what the system temperatures are just after one of these screens. Although it should be fairly to spot an overheated laptop just by touch.

Answer (score 0):

You got that picture just in time!

Based on that, have you installed any new hardware just before the first time you got this problem?

Did you do any task similar to the last time you got this message?

If yes, please say more. If no, I would download a memory checker and run it as this sort of problem is usually attributed to faulty/corrupt memory.

I recommend you use [Memtest86+](http://memtest.org)

Answer (score 0):

before you start testing, its best to actually check what is in the minidump. Here is a list of all [blue screen](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750081.aspx) codes and explanations.

Download windbg and run analyze -v on the minidump. Here are some [instructions](http://cheelam.com/blog/2009/02/09/quick-debugging-blue-screen-of-death-bsod/). I have seen alot of people jump to conclusions and run hours of random tests just to yield nothing. I recommend you inspect the minidump first.

Answer (score 0):

The blue screen can be held.

Go into control panel, System,
click on Advanced system settings in the pane on the left hand side
On the advanced tab, click the bottom settings button in the Startup and recovery area
In the system failure area, untick "Automatically restart".
Click OK to close all the dialogue boxes.